# Json twitter getting the coordinates and message

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, parsing, twitter

I want to get the tweets from this result, but i cannot get a correct input. I want to have the coordinates.

```
 $.ajax(
{
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?&geocode=51.985103,5.89873,1mi',
    success: function (data)
    {
console.log("hoi");
        $.each(data.results, function (i, tweets)
        {

          console.log(tweets);

  for (var j = 0; j < tweets.length; j++)
{
                var tweet = tweets[j];
          console.log(tweet);
}
}
```

I get this as result:

```
   Object { from_user_id_str="237558800", location="ÜT: 51.9901586,5.9141892", more...}
   Object { from_user_id_str="23446954", location="ÜT: 51.983584,5.90971", more...}
   Object { from_user_id_str="237558800", location="ÜT: 51.9901586,5.9141892", more...}
   Object { from_user_id_str="237558800", location="ÜT: 51.9901586,5.9141892", more...}
   Object { from_user_id_str="23446954", location="ÜT: 51.983584,5.90971", more...}
   Object { from_user_id_str="237558800", location="ÜT: 51.9901586,5.9141892", more...}
```

but when i ask tweet i get undefined

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to run a for loop inside of an each statement. your `tweets` object is not an array. You should just change `tweets` to `tweet` since you're pulling them down individually from your `$.each()` method.